# Is it possible to use something similar to JS callbacks in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, callback

Is it possible to do something like...

```
function sum(num1, num2, onComplete)
{
    var result = num1 + num2;
    onComplete(result);
}

(function(){
    sum(3, 5, function(res){alert(res)});
})()
```

In Java?

I would like to do something like what I wrote before without needing to care about the Java version of the user (a general version to do it).

Comment: With Java 8, yes, *somehow*.

Comment: lambdas in Java 8 or single abstract methods before Java 8. Guava also has good solutions for this purpose.

Comment: Why is this question still on hold? The question was re edited and it has even an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Command pattern using Java 6 / 7.

```
public interface Command<T> {
 public void execute(T t);
}
```

then:

```
public void sum(int num1, int num2, Command<Integer> onComplete) {
    int result = num1 + num2;
    onComplete.execute(result);
}
```

Example of usage:

```
someObj.sum(1, 2, new Command<Integer>() {

 public void execute(Integer result) {
  System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What about Java 8?

Comment: As the collegues wrote, Java8 has lambdas. Above solution is applicable for all versions of Java :-) I don't know which version you use and what are the limitations.

Comment: So would you recommend me  to do it as you wrote before, and not with lambdas?

Comment: @gabrielgarcia No, pass lambdas if you can. This solution is good only if you cannot use Java 8.

Comment: Well, it strongly depends on Java version. If you can use newest java 8 - then go for lambdas. But if turns out, you have to migrate to older version of java (lets say 6 or 7) - then you will have a lot of work to rewrite the code to similar as I wrote above.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, will check lambdas right now!

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use Lambdas to do this, in older versions you would have to pass a class or interface that contains the function.

Comment: It is possible before Java 8 (with single abstract methods) but it is verbose.

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle: Yes but you still would pass the class or interface and not the method.

Comment: passing a method in Java 8 is equivalent to pass a class or interface, with syntactic sugar. You actually often pass an instance of `java.util.function.Function` or `java.util.function.Predicate`

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle: That's right, behind the scenes it still passes the interface, just to the user it looks like passing the function.